# Prove/disprove the following equality (sum of inverse difference products)

Tags: summation, inverse

$$\sum_{x\in S}\frac{1}{\prod_{y\in S, y\neq x}(x-y)} = 0$$

Here, S is a finite subset of real numbers.

Comment: Could you show us your work?

Comment: I've only checked this equality for subsets of specific size (up to 4 inclusively, afterwards it gets clunky). Tbh, I partially remember proving this (or something similar) at some point in the past, but I'm having trouble remembering :/

Comment: You should have said this is the post. If the statement is true up to four variables, it is at least some indication that it be true in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n=|S|\geq 2$. Given an arbitrary set of $n$ real values $t_1,\ldots,t_n$, there is a unique$^{(*)}$ polynomial with degree $\leq(n-1)$ such that $p(s_1)=t_1,\ldots,p(s_n)=t_n$ and this polynomial can be constructed via Lagrange interpolation:

$$ p(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} t_k \prod_{j\neq k}\frac{x-s_j}{s_k-s_j}. $$
We may notice that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} t_k \prod_{j\neq k}\frac{1}{s_k-s_j}$$
is the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in $p(x)$.
 If $t_1=\ldots=t_n=1$, the interpolating polynomial is $p(x)=1$ and $\left[x^{n-1}\right]p(x)=0$.

<sup>(*) Incidentally, this also proves that the Vandermonde matrix associated to $s_1,\ldots,s_n$ is invertible.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it! Vandermonde matrix, that's exactly what has been in the back of my mind, couldn't quite recall it ><